# append output of multiple curl requests to a file from shell script

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I'm trying to fetch the JSON output by an internal API and add 100 to a parameter value between cURL requests. I need to loop through because it restricts the maximum number of results per request to 100. I was told to "increment and you should be able to get what you need".

Anyway, here's what I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash

COUNTER=100
until [ COUNTER -gt 30000 ]; do
    curl -vs "http://example.com/locations/city?limit=100&offset=$COUNTER" >> cities.json
    let COUNTER=COUNTER+100
done
```

The problem is that I get a bunch of weird messages in the terminal and the file I'm trying to redirect the output too still contains it's original 100 objects. I feel like I'm probably missing something terrifically obvious. Any thoughts? I did use a somewhat old tutorial on the until loop, so maybe it's a syntax issue?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I'm not opposed to a completely alternate method, but I had hoped this would be somewhat straightforward. I figured my lack of experience was the main limiter.

Comment: Why would it _not_ contain its original content? You're only ever appending.

Comment: With respect to "weird messages to the terminal" -- everything going to curl's stderr is going to be printed to the terminal, and because you're using `curl -v`, that's the behavior you're asking for. If you want different messages printed by curl, I'd suggest deciding what level of verbosity you actually want.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think I was a little imprecise in my original comment. I meant that nothing had been appended when I halted the process - the contents were still the original 100 objects in the file from the first time I used cURL. I stopped the script after a few minutes because the requests were hanging. I also was wrong about the options I was using (I thought -s was supposed to suppress some of the stdout & stderr), so that explains messages in the terminal. I have no formal training, so this is sort of new for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find you can do this faster, and pretty easily with GNU Parallel:

```
parallel -k curl -vs "http://example.com/locations/city?limit=100\&offset={}" ::: $(seq 100 100 30000) > cities.json
```

Comment: I had no experience with parallel until now - thank you! Is this more efficient for loops in your experience? Also, any downsides to using parallel instead of a shell script?

Comment: GNU Parallel is good when you have lots of things to do in parallel, like stripping the metadata from 60,000 images or when you have lots of things to do that have high latency - like `curl` or `ping` where you can *hide* the latency of 7 things behind the latency of the 8th and get a better performance because all those latencies happen in parallel. For essentially sequential things, it is no better. It is an invaluable tool for your toolbox though and pretty quick to give it a try for many problems - so *suck it and see* !

Comment: You may find that you can add `-j 16` after the `-k` to run 16 curls in parallel...

Comment: BTW, _usually_ I tend to argue that `xargs -P` is a better choice than `parallel` (simpler, fewer moving parts, better separation of concerns), but this is a case where that's not true since you need to keep the output collated -- can't have part of one json file mixed with part of another.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to overwrite the file's content only once, for your entire loop...

```
#!/bin/bash
# ^-- NOT /bin/sh, as this uses bash-only syntax

for (( counter=100; counter<=30000; counter+=100 )); do
    curl -vs "http://example.com/locations/city?limit=100&offset=$counter"
done >cities.json
```

This is actually more efficient than putting `>>cities.json` on each `curl` command, as it only opens the output file once, and has the side effect (which you appear to want) of clearing the file's former contents when the loop is started.